# Cloudbees: Customise the "Activating..." page

Tags: java, tomcat7, cloudbees

I'm have a free account on cloudbees and I'm running an application using the tomcat7 stack. Free applications on cloudbees are hibernated after a period of inactivity. If you hit an app that is hibernating, you'll get a page with the text:

## Activating...

I'd like to customise this page to have my own text / javascript. Is this possible on cloudbees?

Answer (score 1):

You can't customize that page because it would mean showing your custom html/javascript page on the URL, which means accessing your application that can't be accessed because it is being activated.

Comment: I was hoping I could provide a static html page for use when the site is in hibernation

Comment: well, I don't think you can, cause otherwise everyone could kind of workaround the hibernation limitation of free apps

Comment: A static html page is static and does not require a JVM / Servlet Container. It would be easy to implement such a feature. It's not working around hibernation because the rest of the app needs a JVM.

Comment: but even if it's just a static html, you would put a pretty "waiting page" so that to overcome the problem of hibernation. The idea is that  users use the free tier for demo apps, and then upgrade to put them in production. Though, I will suggest this to the team, maybe in the future they will consider it.

Comment: Exactly. I want a more user friendly, branded page with a javascript refresh on it.